# Call Java method from GWT app via SWT Browser / SWT BrowserFunction

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, swt, rcp

In a RCP application I am displaying a GWT-based web-application in a SWT Browser.

My Goal is, to call a Java Method from within the GWT application.

From what I understand the easiest way to do that is to use SWT BrowserFunction, which injects a java Method that I can call from within the web-application.

For some reason I'm not able to get it to work...

In RCP I defined the following

```
public class GWTBrowserView extends ViewPart { 
    private GWTBrowser browser; 

    @Override 
    public void createPartControl(final Composite parent) { 
            this.browser = new GWTBrowser(parent, SWT.NONE); 
            this.browser.setUrl("url of gwt app"); 
            new BrowserFunction(this.browser, "onGWTEvent") { 

                    @Override 
                    public Object function(final Object[] arguments) { 
                            // Do something fancy
                            return super.function(arguments); 
                    } 
            }; 
    }
```

In my GWT EntryPoint as part of onModuleLoad I am calling the Method:

```
private native void fireRCPEvent(String rcpEventJSON) /*-{
try{
    onGWTEvent(rcpEventJSON);
} catch(e) {
    alert(e.message)
}
```

Any ideas how to establish the communication between GWT and RCP via the SWT Browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling wrong function from your JSNI. It should be:

```
private native void fireRCPEvent(String rcpEventJSON) /*-{
 try{
    $wnd.onGWTEvent(rcpEventJSON); //notice the usage of $wnd object
 } catch(e) {
    alert(e.message)
 }
}-*/
```

GWT compiled JS code is usually running in some separated context (iframe for example), so you have to explicitly specify that you want to call function from parent window (`$wnd` object), when you need to call external function.